# JSON String is not valid

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using the GSON library to convert the java objects into JSON string. I am adding data to the bean and then I am adding the bean to the Array List. Now I am converting the list to the JSON String with the help of the GSON library. The JSON string is right but the data is incorrect. I tried debugging the code and I found out that during the 1st iteration the bean is added to the list then in the 2nd iteration the bean is overwriting the data of the list which is at position 0 then it is adding itself at position 1.
The list I am expecting:

```
[Bean [fName=Samanyu, lName=Pandit, email=samanyumehra2000@gmail.com, username=sam123, password=null, mobile=7859857230, userImage=IMG/patient.jpg, address=412/A Ganesh Nagar 2 gali no.1 Laxmi Nagar Near Ajay cycles, Mona Pg, specialiasation=Allergist, Dentist, degree=MBBS, BDS, BAMS, experience=3, fees=3], Bean [fName=Samanyu, lName=Mehra, email=samanyumehra20000@gmail.com, username=sam, password=null, mobile=7859857230, userImage=IMG/regis.jpg, address=412/A Ganesh Nagar 2 gali no.1 Laxmi Nagar Near Ajay cycles, Mona Pg, specialiasation=Allergist, Dentist, Anesthesiologist, Cardiologist, Dermatologist, degree=MBBS, BDS, BAMS, BUMS, BHMS, BYNS, experience=3, fees=3]]
```

The list I am getting:

```
[Bean [fName=Samanyu, lName=Mehra, email=samanyumehra20000@gmail.com, username=sam, password=null, mobile=7859857230, userImage=IMG/regis.jpg, address=412/A Ganesh Nagar 2 gali no.1 Laxmi Nagar Near Ajay cycles, Mona Pg, specialiasation=Allergist, Dentist, Anesthesiologist, Cardiologist, Dermatologist, degree=MBBS, BDS, BAMS, BUMS, BHMS, BYNS, experience=3, fees=3], Bean [fName=Samanyu, lName=Mehra, email=samanyumehra20000@gmail.com, username=sam, password=null, mobile=7859857230, userImage=IMG/regis.jpg, address=412/A Ganesh Nagar 2 gali no.1 Laxmi Nagar Near Ajay cycles, Mona Pg, specialiasation=Allergist, Dentist, Anesthesiologist, Cardiologist, Dermatologist, degree=MBBS, BDS, BAMS, BUMS, BHMS, BYNS, experience=3, fees=3]]
```

My Servlet Code:

```
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null,ps2 = null;
        ResultSet rs=null,rs2 = null;
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
        GetUserDetails details=new GetUserDetails();

        String name=request.getParameter("val");
        String sql ="select fName,lName,exp,fees,user_img,username,mob,addr,email from users where fName= ?";
        String sql2="select login_type from users where fName=?";
        String login_type="";

        List<Bean> docSearchList=new ArrayList<Bean>();
        Bean docSearchBean=new Bean();

        if(name==null||name.trim().equals(""))
            out.print("<p>Please enter name!</p>");
        else {
            try {
                con=DBConnection.createConnection();
                ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setString(1, name.trim());
                ps2=con.prepareStatement(sql2);
                ps2.setString(1, name.trim());
                rs=ps.executeQuery();
                rs2=ps2.executeQuery();
                if(!(rs.isBeforeFirst()))
                    out.print("<p>Record not found.</p>");
                else {
                    while(rs2.next())
                        login_type=rs2.getString("login_type");

                    if(!(login_type.equals("D")))
                        out.print("<p>Record not found.</p>");
                    else {
                        while(rs.next()) {
                            String special="";
                            String degree="";
                            List<String> list=details.getSpecialByUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                            special+=list.get(0);
                            for(String s:list) {
                                if(s.equals(special)) {}
                                else 
                                    special+=", "+s;
                            }
                            list=details.getDegByUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                            degree+=list.get(0);
                            for(String s:list) {
                                if(s.equals(degree)) {}
                                else 
                                    degree+=", "+s;
                            }
                            docSearchBean.setfName(rs.getString("fName"));
                            docSearchBean.setlName(rs.getString("lName"));
                            docSearchBean.setExperience(rs.getString("exp"));
                            docSearchBean.setFees(rs.getString("fees"));
                            docSearchBean.setUserImage(session.getAttribute("patientSearchImage")+rs.getString("user_img"));
                            docSearchBean.setMobile(rs.getString("mob"));
                            docSearchBean.setAddress(rs.getString("addr"));
                            docSearchBean.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                            docSearchBean.setDeg(degree);
                            docSearchBean.setSpecial(special);
                            docSearchBean.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));

                            docSearchList.add(docSearchBean);                                   
                        }
                        rs.close();                                                               
                        ps.close();                                                             
                        ps = null;                                                              

                        con.close();                                                             
                        con = null;
                    }
                    Gson gson=new Gson();
                    JsonObject obj=new JsonObject();
                                            
                    JsonElement element=gson.toJsonTree(docSearchList,new TypeToken<List<Bean>>() {}.getType());
                    System.out.println(docSearchList);
                    System.out.println("Element: "+element.toString());
                    if(docSearchBean.getfName()==null)
                        obj.addProperty("success", false);
                    else
                        obj.addProperty("success",true);
                    
                    obj.add("docSearch",element);
                    System.out.println("Obj: "+obj.toString());
                    out.println(obj.toString());
                    out.close();

                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {                                                       
                if (ps != null) {                                            
                    try {                                                         
                        ps.close();     
                    } catch (SQLException sqlex) {                                
                        // ignore -- as we can't do anything about it here           
                    }                                                             
                    ps = null;                                            
                }                                                        
                if (con != null) {                                      
                    try {                                                   
                        con.close();                                          
                    } catch (SQLException sqlex) {                          
                        // ignore -- as we can't do anything about it here     
                    }                                                       
                    con = null;                                            
                }                                                        
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Why don't you tell us what the difference between those big, single line blobs of text is?

Comment: You are using the same instance of `Bean` for every iteration of the loop to read from the database and you are wondering why you are overwriting values? Java is still using objects so if you re-use the same object instance it points to the same object, if you put it into a list or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello to whosoever is reading this, This problem got solved by initializing the bean in the while loop. This occurred because the bean object was using the same values as java points to the same instance of the object.